# Looping through rows counting concurrent values with repeated X times

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I am trying to count number of sequences of the value "Syg", when the concurrent number is greater than 10.

There's formulas in all the cells.

What i need it to do is:

- In Row1, move right to the end,
- count "Syg".
- If "Syg" is repeated 10 times or more, SygCounter = SygCounter + 1
- Input number of 10+ blocks in A1
- Next row

While it is doing this, is there any way to make it also count the number of blocks with "Syg" ? 
So if it's 1 or 5 concurrent "Syg" that's 1 block each.

Thanks for the help in advance, and please let me know if you need more information

[image: Raw data example]

Comment: Just change "Sick" to "Syg" and 10 to 5?

Comment: Oh. I was trying to translate "Syg" to english, and failed miserably.

Comment: I've tried with some ranges and for x to loop through stuff, but i can't seem to make it loop through the cells in question